# Set a custom user role based on registration email in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, registration, user-roles

I added a custom filter to my functions.php file. When I first loaded it up which was a few versions of Woocommerce ago it worked perfectly.

Now it seems that all users are registered as the default 'customer' as opposed to 'student' when their emails do contain `.ac.uk` or `.sch.uk`

The filter function is as follows:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_new_customer_data', 'student_role', 10, 1 );
function student_role( $new_cust_data ) {
    if ( strpos($new_cust_data['user_email'], '.ac.uk' ) >= 1 ) {
        $new_cust_data['role'] = 'student';
    } 
    elseif ( strpos($new_cust_data['user_email'], '.sch.uk') >= 1 ) {
        $new_cust_data['role'] = 'student';
    }
    else {
        $new_cust_data['role'] = 'customer';
    }
    return $new_cust_data;
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `>= 1` with `!== false` in your code *(also it can be simplified)* as follows:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_new_customer_data', 'set_new_customer_user_role_conditionaly' );
function set_new_customer_user_role_conditionaly( $args ) {
    if ( strpos($args['user_email'], '.ac.uk') !== false || strpos($args['user_email'], '.sch.uk') !== false ){
        $args['role'] = 'student';
    }
    return $args;
}
```

It should work.

Comment: I did try it with !== initially but the behaviour was still the same. I'll give your code a try

Comment: @Asim I checked the [source code where `woocommerce_new_customer_data`is located](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/tree/4.9.2/includes/wc-user-functions.php#L41-L109), and there is no changes… so that is really strange. Maybe you have made some changes somewhere else, enabled a plugin or updated the theme. There is something else that is making trouble.

Comment: Maybe I'll diagnose. So far I know that if I set `$args['role'] = 'student'`; within the filter it works. But the strpos() doesn't seem to as expected.