# Automatically set Custom Role based on email domain at registration in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have searched for an answer but none seems to work, I hope to have a better look there also if the question is n00b!

I am trying to automatically set a custom role (already defined) at registration, based on the email domain (i.e. *custom-domain.com*) of the user.

So far I have tried this

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'wp234_set_role_by_email' );
function wp234_set_role_by_email( $user_id ){
    $user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );
    $domain = substr(
        strrchr(
            $user->data->user_email, 
            "@"
        ), 1
    ); //Get Domain

    $contributor_domains = array( 'custom-domain.com' );
    if( in_array( $domain, $contributor_domains ) ){
        foreach( $user->roles as $role )
        $user->remove_role( $role ); //Remove existing Roles
        $user->add_role( 'author' ); //Add role.
    }
}
```

I have also tried [Set a custom user role based on registration email in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66050292/set-a-custom-user-role-based-on-registration-email-in-woocommerce/66050872#66050872) answer code, but have no luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PHP [**`strpos()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function to check if the customer's email address contains a specific string (domain).

If the `user_register` hook does not work and you are using WooCommerce you can replace it with the [**`woocommerce_created_customer`**](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-wc-user-functions.html#source-view.105) hook which **is activated when a new customer is created**.

If you use the same hook multiple times **set a priority to make sure the function runs after all the others** *(according to your needs)*.

```
// set custom user role based on email
add_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer', 'wp234_set_role_by_email' );
function wp234_set_role_by_email( $user_id ) {

    // initializes the control variable
    $found = false;

    // get user's email based on user id
    $user_email = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id )->user_email;
    // defines the domains to compare with
    $contributor_domains = array( 'custom-domain.com' );

    // for each domain
    foreach ( $contributor_domains as $domain ) {
        // if the email address contains one of the domains
        if ( strpos( $user_email, $domain ) ) {
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // if it is found
    if ( $found ) {
        // gets the user's object
        $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
        // set the custom user role
        $user->set_role( 'author' );
    }
}
```

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*