# Set the user Role based on custom Field on Registration Woocomerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, user-roles

I need something to automatic change role to subscriber when user type this `547889` number in registration.

I found this [Set a custom user role based on registration email in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66050292/set-a-custom-user-role-based-on-registration-email-in-woocommerce/66050872#66050872) that looks familiar but no luck.

can you guys check if my code was correct?

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'set_role_via_custom_number' );
function set_role_via_custom_number( $user_id ){
    $user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );
    $fregadditional = substr(
        strrchr(
            $user->data->user_afreg_additional_101
        ), 1
    );

    $editor_fregadditional = array( '547889' );
    if( in_array( $fregadditional, $editor_fregadditional ) ){
        foreach( $user->roles as $role )
            $user->remove_role( $role ); //Remove existing Roles
        $user->add_role( 'subscriber' ); //Add role
    }

}
```

Comment: _"when user type this 547889 number in registration."_ - 
In a default registration there is no possibility to enter a number, so you will have to clarify that. and what is the meaning or purpose of `$user->data->user_afreg_additional_101`, that doesn't seem to be part of the default properties of `$user`

Comment: its a custom field meta name in registration `$user->data->user_afreg_additional_101`

Comment: OK, so it's about wrong application. However, you still haven't mentioned how the custom field was added to the registration form, that is necessary so that your question contains [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)